# Can a rod develop emf if magnetic field changes nearby?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, voltage

This is because of this question
[image]

What I don't understand is that whatever magnetic business is happening,it's not directly in contact with rod, as far as I know a rod can develop emf if its travelling in magnetic field with a velocity.
In the solution they constructed a square around circle and then emf was calculated and divided by 4.I don't understand why such a thing could be done, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travelling rod would develop *motional* EMF. Here the rod is at rest, so the EMF is purely due to induced electric field due to body that is the source of the magnetic field.

This body has cylindrical symmetry, so the induced electric field points everywhere in direction of a tangent to a concentric circle there.

Induced EMF for the line is integral of this induced field along that line, but it is cumbersome to directly calculate. There is trick though: net EMF for a centered square that contains the whole magnetic field is known (equal to rate of change of magnetic flux) and due to symmetry it has to be 4 times EMF for single side of the square.

Comment: Ok so is this coming from maxwell equations, I know only faintly, but is it the case that changing magnetic fields produce electric fields in free space too?

Comment: When magnetic field changes in space, there is also induced electric field in that space. Where, how strong, which direction can be found from Maxwell's equations and boundary conditions. Usually it is assumed that all fields are retarded and can be traced back to state of charges in the past. So it is the charges that produce electric field and magnetic field.